# Как значение вывести в текстовую строку?

Tags: php, html

Вот код программы:

```
<?php
$file="cena3.txt";
$open=fopen($file,"r+");
$read=fread($file,100000);
fclose($open);
echo "<form action=redaktor.php method=GET>";
echo "<input type=text value=$read name=cena1>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

в переменную $read я вписываю значение. Как мне это значение вывести в текстовую строку

```
<input type=text value=$read name=cena1>
```

У меня не получается... строка выводится, но в ней нет мной заранее вписанного ***$read***.

Comment: Заведите себе за правило атрибуты тегов в html помещать в двойные кавычки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно ваш вопрос можно сформулировать так "почему у меня в $read пусто?".

```
$file = "{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/cena1.txt";
$read = file_get_contents($file);
echo "<form action=redaktor.php method=GET>";
echo "<input type=text value=\"$read\" name=cena1>";
echo "</form>";
```

Это работает отлично.

Answer (score 3):

Параметры html нужно указывать в кавычках.

```
echo "<form action=\"redaktor.php\" method=\"GET\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$read\" name=\"cena1\">";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в кавычках:

```
<?php
$file="cena3.txt";
$open=fopen($file,"r+");
$read=fread($file,100000);
fclose($open);
echo "<form action=\"redaktor.php\" method=\"GET\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$read\" name=\"cena1\">";
echo "</form>";
?>
```